# Commutative Diagrams with internal mappings

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-cd

I'd like to produce a commutative diagram with mappings specified inside it, as follows:

[image: Yoneda]

My rankly amateur efforts so far have centered on tikzcd with extra columns and rows, as in

```
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[ 
\begin{tikzcd}
Zap \arrow{rrr}{foo} 
    \arrow{ddd}{bar} & & & Zoom \arrow{ddd}{bar} \\
    & Foo \arrow[mapsto]{r}{\alpha}
      \arrow[mapsto]{d}{\beta}
    & Bar \arrow[mapsto]{d}{\gamma} & \\
& Baz \arrow[mapsto]{r}{\delta}
        & Bong & \\
Zip \arrow[anchor=north]{rrr}{foo} & & & Zop
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

This is uglier than the figure above. What's a better way to do this?

EDIT:

The suggestion of Stephen Segletes below showed a gentleman who demands more of his commutative diagrams. I salute him, and commend to you the following magisterial display of elegance, beauty and power:

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{stackengine}[2013-09-11]
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
\[ 
\stackinset{l}{13ex}{b}{6ex}{%
\scalebox{.8}
{% 
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=8ex, column sep = 8ex, ampersand replacement=\&]
1_C 
    \arrow[mapsto]{r}
    \arrow[mapsto]{d}
\& \vartheta_C1_C = x^{\vartheta} 
    \arrow[mapsto]{d}  \\
f 
    \arrow[mapsto]{r} 
\& \begin{array}{c}Ff\left(x^{\vartheta}\right)=\\\vartheta_D\left(f\right)\end{array}
\end{tikzcd}
} 
}{% 
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep = 20ex, column sep = 20ex, ampersand replacement=\&]
Hom\left(C,C\right) 
    \arrow{r}{\vartheta_C} 
    \arrow[swap]{d}{f}
\& FC 
    \arrow{d}{Ff}  \\
Hom\left(D,C\right) 
    \arrow[swap]{r}{\vartheta_D} 
\& FD
\end{tikzcd}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

This renders as 
[image: raw beauty]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  In particular, it is always best to provide a complete compilable sample document, rather than a code snippet.

Comment: I don't think you can get any better, because of the wide formula in the inner lower right corner. I'd make two smaller diagrams side by side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pardon me for not knowing tikz, so my diagram does not contain arrows, but lines.  But the idea is here.  Create two diagrams, and inset the one over the center of the other.  In this case, I made the inner diagram smaller in tikz (size 2 vs. 4), but I also scaled it by 80% to show the fonts smaller on the inset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{stackengine}[2013-09-11]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\centering
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{%
\scalebox{.8}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {$Foo$};
\node (B) at (2,0) {$Bar$};
\node (C) at (0,-2) {$Baz$};
\node (D) at (2,-2) {$Bong$};
\draw (A) edge node[above] {$\alpha$} (B);
\draw (C) edge node[below] {$\delta$} (D);
\draw (A) edge node[left] {$\beta$} (C);
\draw (B) edge node[right] {$\gamma$} (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {$Zap$};
\node (B) at (4,0) {$Zoom$};
\node (C) at (0,-4) {$Zip$};
\node (D) at (4,-4) {$Zap$};
\draw (A) edge node[above] {$foo$} (B);
\draw (C) edge node[below] {$foo$} (D);
\draw (A) edge node[left] {$bar$} (C);
\draw (B) edge node[right] {$bar$} (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]